# Composite c1 static data type interface implementation

Tags: inheritance, types, interface, static

I'm creating data types through C#. I would like to hav a base interface containing properties used by every C# created data types. But when implement the base interface the data type is gone from the UI. Is there any special properties I need to set to be able to implement a base interface?

This works:

```
[AutoUpdateble]
[KeyPropertyName("Id")]
[LabelPropertyName("Id")]
[ImmutableTypeId("{96071614-AC10-4741-8BEA-8D1720B4BBE9}")]
[DataScope(DataScopeIdentifier.PublicName)]
[DataAncestorProvider(typeof(NoAncestorDataAncestorProvider))]
[RelevantToUserType(UserType.Developer)]
[PublishProcessControllerType(typeof(GenericPublishProcessController))]
public interface IProduct : IPublishControlled, ILocalizedControlled
{
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.Guid)]
    [ImmutableFieldId("{F728357F-CD1E-49F9-8EB7-09AB5317248E}")]
    Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 249)]
    [ImmutableFieldId("{9F551C4C-99BA-46C5-9BC5-9AE0A2EB00ED}")]
    string Title { get; set; }
}
```

If I add the interface (IBase) below to the (IProduct) it doesnt work

```
[KeyPropertyName("Id")]
[ImmutableTypeId("{DA2B4217-71BE-4225-8059-7E846D7EDA0D}")]
[DataScope(DataScopeIdentifier.PublicName)]
[DataAncestorProvider(typeof(NoAncestorDataAncestorProvider))]
[RelevantToUserType(UserType.Developer)]
[PublishProcessControllerType(typeof(GenericPublishProcessController))]
public interface IBase 
{
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.Guid)]
    [ImmutableFieldId("{66946660-5E2A-4B19-9FFF-B9861CFF9274}")]
    Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.Integer)]
    [ImmutableFieldId("{40A9F106-B634-49B6-9157-BFCE232C362D}")]
    int SortOrder { get; set; }

    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 249)]
    [ImmutableFieldId("{72EBBE55-FB0D-496C-A316-0CD8765C10FC}")]
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Please any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Johan,
If you want create inherited types..your IBase should look like this:

```
public interface IBase 
{
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.Integer)]
    [ImmutableFieldId("{40A9F106-B634-49B6-9157-BFCE232C362D}")]
    int SortOrder { get; set; }

    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 249)]
    [ImmutableFieldId("{72EBBE55-FB0D-496C-A316-0CD8765C10FC}")]
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

so we killed interface attributes and Id. And now you can do this:

public interface IProduct : IPublishControlled, ILocalizedControlled, IBase